# getting circular dependency error when I am throwing a error in typeScript

Tags: typescript

I encountered an error in the following code:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> The issue begins with an object created using the 'Socket' constructor.

The error occurred when I attempted to throw an error message. Specifically, the error appeared when executing the line "if(!group) throw Error".

Can someone help me fixing this error? I am using typescript here.

```
  async updateGroup(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const { body: params } = request
      const group = await this.groupRepository.findOne(params.id)
  
      if (!group) {
        throw new Error("Group not found")
      }
  
      const updateGroupInput: UpdateGroupInput = {
        id: params.id,
        name: params.name
      }
  
      group.updateConstructor(updateGroupInput)
      const updatedGroup = await this.groupRepository.save(group)
      return response.status(200).json(updatedGroup)
    } catch (error) {
      return response.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error", error })
    }
  }
```

New Case where I am getting the same error:

```
  async runFilter(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        return response.status(200).json({})

}
```

Comment: Can you try to log `updatedGroup `

Comment: @kennarddh I tried it but I only received an error message(circular dependency error) and not the updateGroup data

Comment: What line caused that error?

Comment: @kennarddh This line:    throw new Error("Group not found")

Comment: Different error?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a `socket` to JSON directly.  There are several fields that must be omitted with the `replacer` argument, by keying on those fields and returning `undefined` from the `replacer` function.

`JSON.stringify(value, replacer)`

Figure out what field contains the `socket` object, and exclude it from your `replacer`.  Then return your JSON string directly with the proper content type.

Comment: Hey

I am still not able to figure out the issue. I'll give you one more case where I am getting this error. I'll post the new case in the post

Comment: Have you tried not calling ‘return’

Comment: Somewhere in your code a socket object is getting serialized. It could eventually be an error handler.